# How to persist a list of objects in disk and update them using Java

Tags: java, caching

I'm using EhCache for an application to cache response on REST APIs. Since Fast Restart is not available in open source version of the application, I cannot asynchronously write my cache to disk which I can use later if the application crashes or shutdown.

I want to write all cached elements to a data store in disk. I want to be able to update the element on the disk when the element changes in Cache. EhCache has event notifiers to notify of any change in elements in cache. I started with serializing the objects using FileOutputStream. But updating on event seems to be too much - reading through the file and updating the file, optimistically. Is there an open source library that could serialize my java objects into disk and I can quickly lookup and update them ?

Comment: I'm using MapDB instead of EhCache.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using EhCache for an application to cache response on REST APIs.

If the question is "How to cache REST responses?", then the answer is: Set appropriate HTTP response headers and put a caching edge server like NGINX oder Varnish in front of your application.

Comment: The JSON response of REST API is converted to a java object. I want to cache the Java object for other reasons. I wrote about REST API to mention source of data, but looks like that is irrelevant to this question.